# VBA error caused by iterating past expected stopping point

Tags: vba, excel

**Background:**
I am attempting to convert an old style of managing departments, facilities, and job titles at work to a new more convenient lookup table style format. Right now each set of data for new departments, facilities, and job titles are stored on separate sheets (a couple per week) and the sheet name is a date.

**The issue:**
The program runs fine for the majority of the workbook; however, I eventually get a

> 1004 - Application-defined or objected-defined error

When debugging, I find that my row value has to 1,048,577 and therefore caused the error. I am unsure how the iterating value is escaping my handling of it.

**The code:**

```
Sub cleanUp()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wksNum As Long
Dim destWks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim destRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim itemType As String


Set destWks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("new")
destRow = 2

For wksNum = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
NextWks:
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wksNum)

    If wks.Name = "new" Then
        wksNum = wksNum + 1
        GoTo NextWks
    End If

    lastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    For row = 1 To lastRow
NextRow:
            Select Case wks.Cells(row, 1).Value
                Case "New Hospitals"
                    itemType = "Hospital"
                    row = row + 1
                    GoTo NextRow
                Case "New Departments"
                    itemType = "Department"
                    row = row + 1
                    GoTo NextRow
                Case "New Job Titles"
                    itemType = "Job Title"
                    row = row + 1
                    GoTo NextRow
                Case "none"
                    row = row + 1
                    GoTo NextRow
                Case ""
                    row = row + 1
                    GoTo NextRow
            End Select
            destWks.Cells(destRow, 1).Value = wks.Name
            destWks.Cells(destRow, 2).Value = itemType
            wks.Range("A" & row & ":C" & row).Copy destWks.Range("C" & destRow)
            destRow = destRow + 1
    Next row

Next wksNum

End Sub
```

**Example Sheet:**

```
New Hospitals   
None    

New Departments 
10 146 7205-DeptA
10 193 9178-DeptB   

New Job Titles  
004315  JobTitleA
```

**A side question:**
Is there a more elegant way of skipping to the next iteration of a for loop without using a `GoTo` statement. My thoughts are that these are causing my issue.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: the problem is your `Case ""` section and all the `GoTo`s  please explain your logic behind the `Select Case`  as it seems to set a variable then skip doing anything with that variable as it reiterates.

Comment: So you are already aware that Excel has a maximum row limit of 1,048,576. With that many rows, you may be better of processing this using a database instead, since you have reached the limit.

Comment: Your `Case ""` is the culprit.  In that case, you are incrementing `row` and then doing a `GoTo NextRow`.  At that point you start processing one row further than your loop counter is at, and each subsequent time through that case puts you one further ahead again.  So, a single blank cell in your data will mean you will end up processing at least the cell one beyond the last used cell - and once you start processing that you will be in a loop that takes you to the last cell in the worksheet.

Comment: No, forget I said that - `row` **is** your loop counter.  So the issue isn't as bad as I was making out - I think it would only be an issue if the last row was one of the ones being tested for in the `Case` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is if your data on any sheet ends with either of the group headings or `none` then it will start an eternal loop adding 1 to `row` until it reaches a row number that is not supported by the worksheet.

You have taken the loop outside the For Loop and so it does not stop.

It is better to test for the opposite and do the code instead of using the archaic `Goto`.

Use this:

```
Sub cleanUp()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wksNum As Long
Dim destWks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim destRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim itemType As String

Set destWks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("new")
destRow = 2

For wksNum = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wksNum)

    If wks.Name <> "new" Then
        lastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

        For row = 1 To lastRow
            Select Case wks.Cells(row, 1).Value
                Case "New Hospitals", "New Departments", "New Job Titles"
                    itemType = Replace(wks.Cells(row, 1).Value, "New ", "")
                Case "None", ""
                Case Else
                    destWks.Cells(destRow, 1).Value = wks.Name
                    destWks.Cells(destRow, 2).Value = itemType
                    wks.Range("A" & row & ":C" & row).Copy destWks.Range("C" & destRow)
                    destRow = destRow + 1
            End Select

        Next row
    End If
Next wksNum

End Sub
```

---

Edited to simplify `Select Case` based on Scott Holtzman's now deleted answer

Output with provided data:

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks for the help! So instead of trying to advance a for loop early, try to change the way criteria is being tested for. I would imagine that your method of using an `if not` would be applicable to most situations like this?